# Selenium Test to recursively locate elements very slow

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm a newbie to selenium.

I'm trying to traverse all the elements in a dropdown box on a webpage with a lot of sub elements. I'm doing this to get all the href attributes on all the options in the select tags.
I'm finding elements using the Xpath expressions.

I'm using Selenium WebDriver along with FireFox browser. The results are what I expect but the test is extremely slow.

If there any way in which I can make the test faster by using any alternative approach?

This the code I'm using -

```
private void captureElements(String xpath)
{ 

  List<WebElement> list=null;

    if((list=driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)))!=null){ 

       int length = list.size(); int i=length;

        while(i>0){ 

          WebElement ele = list.get(length-i); 
          Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
          builder.moveToElement(ele).build().perform(); 

          LogElementToExcel(ele); 

          int index = length-i+1; 
          String newxpath = xpath.replace("/a", "["+index+"]/ul/li/a");  
          captureElements(newxpath); 
          i--; 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Perhaps use one XPath to get the nodeset that consists of all of the options, rather than one XPath per option?

Comment: can you post your source? I d prefer cssSelector over xpath. Besides you can get all options from a dropdown without cssSelector or xpath with `Select select = new Select(webElement); List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions()`. The code is java. Which language are u using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running tests in firefox which has native xpath engine. So it's hard to tell why your test is slow unless you provide the code. Xpath is slow in IE because IE doesn't have a native xpath engine but that doesn't seem to be your issue at this point.

I am thinking below would be faster than your xpath solution. Give it a shot.

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("idOfMySelectBox"));
Select select = new Select(element);
List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
for(WebElement option:options){
    System.out.println(option.getAttribute("href"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [Selenium 2.0 IE Xpath Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705659/selenium-2-0-ie-xpath-performance)

Given your scenario, I think you would be better off loading the page source into a library like HtmlAgilityPack and parsing it that way - you'll see a huge performance boost.  For languages other than C#, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping).

Answer (score 0):

Automation with any GUI tool such as selenium is slow, the proxy starting the browser is a slow process, the complete displaying of all GUI elements is also a slow process. If speed is a factor dont forget you can do equally comprehensive test with headless tools.  The execution time can be reduced by as much as 40%.  Once tool I have worked with is JWebUnit.  try it for speed.